# Close connection to DB in every view function , Django

Tags: python, django, psql

I'm having a problem with my connections to DB, as too many connections keep being alive which cause me the error `too many connections for the role ( XXXXX)` as XXXX is the name of the role.

now I've used this method inside every function in the **views.py** to avoid this

```
@login_required
def notifications(request):
    for conn in connections.all():
        conn.close()
    dress_need = Item.objects.filter(dress_active=False).order_by('-created_at')
    dress_need_count = dress_need.count()
    context = {
        'dress_need_count': dress_need_count,
        'dress_need': dress_need,
    }

    return render(request, 'fostania_web_app/notifications.html', context)
```

as you see I used

```
for conn in connections.all():
    conn.close()
```

in every single view function...

but it still happens .. any idea how to add something that closes every connection when it is done?

Comment: Why do you open connections manually? Typically if you use the Django ORM, then Django will maintain a connection pool, this more efficient as well as more safe. Closing connections is not only unsafe, it is inefficient, since it means you need to setup a new connection every time, and opening a connection has some cost as well.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem looks like I've used a bad function as an example... edited it  - isn't this ORM ?? `dress_need = Item.objects.filter(dress_active=False).order_by('-created_at')`

Comment: Django automatically closes connections after request processing by defualt, so you shouldn't do it manually. Did you set CONN_MAX_AGE variable in your data base settings?

Comment: @DimaKudosh am only using this setting as I found in another thread. `db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()`

Comment: @DimaKudosh any help on how to set CONN_MAX_AGE?

Comment: I don't know because you use third-party library for it. Try to change your code to this `dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=0)`